# Photoshop: Converting to Grayscale and then setting darkest value to 60% black

Tags: adobe-photoshop, grayscale

Once you have a color picture converted to grayscale, how could you tell photoshop to set the darkest color to 60% black and then shift the rest of the tones accordingly?

EDIT: To give some context, I am putting a list of my clients on my website and am converting all their logos to gray scale but I don't want the logos to be full opacity black, rather a tone of gray at their darkest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a new layer below the greyscale layer and fill it with white.

Select the greyscale layer and set the opacity to 60%.

or....

`Image > Adjustments > Curves`

Click the upper point of the output curve... then set the **Output value** to 60....

[image]

Max output will be 60%.

There are probably additional ways to accomplish this as well.

Answer (score 2):

It's real easy actually once you are converted to grayscale, hold your mouse over the darkest part of your image and looking at my image look at the info panel.. You will see it says 100% K.  that means where my mouse is at that moment is 100% black.

[image]

The next thing you need to do is go to your layers panel and adjust the fill property slider down to 60%.  And just to doublecheck, after sliding the filter down to 60% put your mouse back at that location where it was darkest and look at the info in the info panel. It should now say K 60

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can but White color layer underneath and change the opacity for the logo layer to 60%

[image]